# How to break text of title property of DIV

Tags: html, title, break

In below div, I want to break the text of title property(want to display company id, name and activities in different lines). Can anyone suggest me the best way to solve this problem. 
Thanks

DIV id="window6" class="component window" style="top:300px;left:250px;" title="CompanyID:25 Name:Company  25 Activities:,INVHLDGS,  MallOwned:123 " 
6000000

/DIV

Comment: There is no above div, could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the tool tip displayed for the div title to have line breaks then how about using a jquery plugin like this one: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

You can add `<br />` tags to the pop up content (data-content):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="a=1<br /> b=2<br />" data-original-title="A Title">hover for popover</a>
```

I see the JS Bootstrap online example uses an "a" tag, but it should also work with a "div" tag. NB: this plugin also requires that the Tooltip library be included. Read their documentation if you like this plugin. Of course their are many other similar plugins, especially with jQuery that may have this specific function.